# Evaluation metric for imbalanced data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, class-imbalance, anomaly-detection, model-evaluations

Hi I'm a CS graduate student

I have a question for AI or data experts. I'm writing a paper

My dataset is time-series sensor data and anomaly (positive class) ratio is between 5% and 6%

you can see the picture below. I used *classification_report* in *sklearn* library

[image]

But, I'm confused as to what value to report in my evaluation section ...

I think it is reasonable to report f1-score with macro avg (0.40)

Is it ok?

Thank you for your explanation !

Comment: [Your collaborator asked this on Cross Validated.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/533013/evaluation-metric-for-imbalanced-data) I suggest the same that I suggested there.

Comment: I recommend reading related papers and check which measures are being reported there.

Answer (score 0):

Classic evaluation metrics are heavily affected by skewed data. In your case, since you have imbalanced data, you should definitely avoid those such as accuracy. For example,

Imagine you have a test data with 100 records. 3 of them have Class A and 97 have Class B. I create this model:

```
prediction = "B"
```

Simple as that, I always give the second class. I will get accuracy of 97%, but I fail to predict any of the records I really care.

This is important in cases like cancer prediction where early detection is important.

What you could use instead:

- Sensitivity
- Specificity
- G-Mean
- F-Measure
- Class weighted metrics where you give more weight to the smaller one

Comment: Thank you for your explanation ! Um.. Do you think ROC-AUC is also a good measure?

Answer (score 0):

For an imbalanced dataset, you should report the base rate (5% anomaly, 95% regular observation), alongside your selected score; without that, the interpretation can lead to base-rate fallacy.

The common metrics derived from the [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) will do. Be careful with ROC AUC, it tends to be over-optimistic compared to accuracy and is generally less understandable by practitioners. For highly imbalanced datasets, ROC AUC will be very close to 1 most of the time.

I personally like paired metrics, such as precision-recall, or specificity-sensitivity, which report separately type I and type II errors.

There are also metrics, which weigh these two errors unequally. F1-score focuses on the lower, e.g., precision 0.1, and recall 0.9 yields F1 0.18.

Check out the USENIX paper [Do's and Don'ts of Machine Learning in Computer Security](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/sec22summer_arp.pdf), which mentions metrics used for imbalanced datasets.